# Problema na utilização do char string

Tags: c

Galera me ajuda: o exercício que estou tentando fazer é 4. Escreva um programa em que:

a) Seja lido um caractere que deve ser uma das vogais do alfabeto, podendo ser maiúsculas ou minúsculas.

b) Seja implementada uma função em que verifique qual vogal foi lida, imprima, na própria função, uma das seguintes mensagens, conforme o caso:

> 1ª vogal,
>
> 2ª vogal,
>
> 3ª vogal,
>
> 4ª vogal,
>
> 5ª vogal ou
>
> Outro caractere

Alguém pode dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

char VogaLida (char Vogal [], int TamanhoVetor);


int main (){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");

    char Vogal [] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    char VogalLida;

    printf("Informe uma vogal: ");
    gets(Vogal);

    VogalLida = VogaLida(Vogal, 5);

}

char VogaLida (char Vogal [], int TamanhoVetor)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        if (i == Vogal[0]) {
            Vogal[0] = 'a' | 'A';
            printf("1ª Vogal\n");

            return 0;
        }
        else if (i == Vogal[1]){
            Vogal[1] = 'e' | 'E';
            printf("2ª Vogal\n");

             return 0;
        }

        else if (i == Vogal[2]){
            Vogal[2] = 'i' | 'I';
            printf("3ª Vogal\n");

             return 0;
        }


        else if (i == Vogal[3]){
            Vogal[3] = 'o' | 'O';
            printf("4ª Vogal\n");

             return 0;
        }

    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se a resposta do Christian resolveu o teu problema podes marcá-la como aceite. Senão podes dar uma resposta tua para explicar a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Seu programa tá bugado cara, a lógica está com problemas.

1. Você está lendo um caractere com a função `gets()` e colocando no vetor que tinha os seus caracteres `Vogal`, sendo que você só precisa ler um caractere.
2. Depois que você chama o método `VogalLida` que faz a verificação das vogais porém você utiliza o `i` que é um número inteiro para fazer as comparações dentro do bloco **for**.
3. ...

Na verdade, não tem como eu explicar tudo por aqui, então siga o raciocío:

1) Segundo o seu **prinf()** você só quer ler uma letra para verificar se ela é uma vogal. Então experimente o `getc()` e salve em uma variável **char**.

2)Faça a função `VogalLida(char vogal)` com o seguinte corpo:

```
void VogalLida(char vogal)
{
    switch(vogal)
    {
        case 'a': printf("1ª Vogal\n"); break;
        case ...;
        default: printf("Nao eh vogal\n");
    }
}
```

Agora é só implementar os demais casos, do jeito que você implementou você usou muitos recursos e acabou embolando a lógica.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Christian ! Depois que eu postei aqui minha dúvida eu consegue resolver e vi que minha lógica estava muito errada. Agradeço de qualquer maneira sua disposição em ajudar. Valeu.

Comment: Beleza cara, tamo aí pra ajudar. Mas depois dê uma olhada no [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para você entender um pouco melhor do StackOverflow e de como sinalizar seu agradecimento com as respostas, porque aí você me ajuda também!